# Android centralize textview vertical

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, textview

I use  `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` property to centre textview , it works fine in lvl 18 and 19, but not works in lvl 16. This is whole layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="45dp"
    p1:minHeight="45dp"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:gravity="fill_vertical"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <TextView
        p1:text="Text"
        p1:visibility="invisible"
        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/item_id" />
    <TextView
        p1:text="Text"
        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_height="47dp"
        p1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        p1:id="@+id/name"
        p1:textColor="@color/black"
        p1:layout_centerVertical="true"
        p1:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>
    <ImageView
        p1:src="@drawable/details_icon"
        p1:layout_width="60px"
        p1:layout_height="47dp"
        p1:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        p1:id="@+id/imageView1"
        p1:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <LinearLayout
        p1:orientation="horizontal"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="1dp"
        p1:layout_below="@id/forecastName"
        p1:background="@drawable/separator"
        p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        p1:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

how to set text centre of layout in prev versions?

Comment: What is `p1` in your `XML`?

Comment: I think it should work in all versions, no restrictions in it.

Comment: this is xamarin and it sometime uses p1 prefix

Comment: i add  p1:gravity="center_vertical" , it works now  ^_^

Comment: @NinoSvanidze great, then keep it up

Comment: @NinoSvanidze In which project are you working now nino?

Comment: @NinoSvanidze hello there?